# MVC Routing for IIS and Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I think I have a fairly easy issue to fix but I can't seem to get it to work as I need. When running the web app through Visual Studio I get a URL such as: `http://localhost:50261/Controller/Action` But when I deploy it to IIS the URL is setup like so: `http://devServer/AppName/Controller/Action`.

I'm having an issue with my ajax URL requests not getting routed correctly. When running the web app locally my ajax URL is: `/Controller/Action` but when I deploy to the dev IIS I have to change it to: `/AppName/Controller/Action` for the ajax request to get routed correctly.

So I've been trying to create the correct mapRoute to leave my ajax URL to `/AppName/Controller/Action` so I don't have to adjust it each time I deploy. This is what I have right now thats not working:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Survey", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Dev", // Route name
                "AppName/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "DefaultController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

With these routes if I try the URL: `http://localhost:50261/AppName/` it can't find anything. I'm a little confused at what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should have waiting a little longer until posting my question on SO, I figured it out. I was going to delete the question but, in case someone else runs across this I thought I'd leave it.

My issue had nothing to do with MVC Routing, but more with the Visual Studio Development Server's settings. All I had to do is correctly put in the "Virtual path" to match my IIS structure and now the web app works locally and when deployed without making changes.